# GUI Password protect a folder in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, password

I have a few folders in Ubuntu 22.04 that I want to add password protection to. Is there any GUI tool that can do this? Something safe and reliable? Thanks.

Comment: Simple e.g.: https://eck.cologne/peafactory/en/html/file_pea.html … Resourceful e.g.: https://www.ecryptfs.org/

Comment: Those will encrypt, which is the most secure way … Adding a password to a directory on the other hand is first insecure and second you can do it easily by changing directory/files permissions/ownership from your DE file manager in the GUI.

Comment: This can however be done with encryption as a second layer of security .. To e.g. prevent listing and viewing the contents of a directory.

Comment: Allow me some time to try. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Take all of this with the disclaimer that the methods that someone should take to protect data are deeply personal to the situation. You need to take into account your particular threat model. You need to evaluate *who* could attack you, *how* they might do it, *what* you're trying to protect, and *how bad* would it be if the info was compromised.

Simply putting a password on a folder doesn't really provide any protection. It offers no better protection than putting your name on food in a shared refrigerator.

Use encryption instead. You can create an encrypted volume using software like VeraCrypt and you can use a password to unlock the encrypted container.

Keep in mind that this doesn't provide perfect protection either. For example, applications often make cache and temporary files when you're working with them. These would be stored outside of the encrypted container and therefore subject to being accessed by a nefarious third party.  Full disk encryption should be used if this is a concern.